# How to set 1 div next to 2 siblings divs inside parent div with flex?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am trying to set a layout like this:
[image: desired layout]

But with code bellow I only get the first two divs set properly but the third one is out of `div.outer`. How to set this properly with CSS flex? I made it so far with `float: left` but I want to do it in flexbox.
If we will have more than 3 div.inner there should be stack starting from the left (if there is no more space at right)

```css
.outer {
   width: 100%;
   border: 2px solid black;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   height:500px;
 }

 .inner {
   width: 50%;
   border: 2px solid red;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   
 }

.inner:first-child {
  height:100%
}

.inner:nth-child(n+2) {
  height:50%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to modify the markup?

Comment: try to add .outer flex-direction:column;

Comment: @JamesCoyle no, also number of children could be diffrent than 3

Comment: @godfather it's works with 3 inner but how about more inner divs??

Comment: @Paul what should be the result when more than 3 inner divs. Please edit your question for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the same markup, you can add `margin-left: auto` to the *third* `inner` and *translate* it towards the top using `transform: translate(-100%)` - see demo below:

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
}

.inner {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner:first-child {
  height: 100%;
}

.inner:nth-child(n+2) {
  height: 50%;
}

.inner:last-child { /* ADDED */
  margin-left: auto;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same inner for the left and the right box as their width is the same.
Then put two more inners inside the right inner, see here.

```css
    .outer {
           width: 100%;
           border: 2px solid black;
           box-sizing: border-box;
           display: flex;
           flex-wrap: wrap;
           height:500px;
         }
        
         .inner {
           width: 50%;
           border: 1px solid red;
           box-sizing: border-box;
           height: 100%;
         }
        
        .inner-inner {
          width: 100%;
          height: 50%;
          border: 1px solid green;
        }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
          <div class="inner"></div>
          <div class="inner">
             <div class="inner-inner"></div>
             <div class="inner-inner"></div>
          </div>
    </div>
```